# Problem accessing MySQL connection out of Flask methods

Tags: python-3.x, flask, mqtt, mysql-python

I'm developing a Flask app, with MySQL (flask-mysqldb) and MQTT (flask-mqtt) integrations. I can perform any DB operation from a Flask method (e.g. `@app.route('/')`), but if I try to do it from a MQTT method when I receive a message (e.g. `@mqtt.on_message()`) it does nothing. This last method works perfectly because it receives and shows in log the message received.

I have a method that performs DB operations, and depending on where I call it from, it works or not. I guess it should be because of the MySQL object, but I don't know exactly.

Here is the code I'm using (just the problem):

```
@mqtt.on_message()
def handle_mqtt_message(client, userdata, message):
    print('New message {}'.format(message.payload.decode()))
    storeDB('test') #Here it doesn't work


################## Methods ###########################


def storeDB(param_text):
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        'INSERT INTO contacts (fullname, phone, email) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)', (param_text, param_text, param_text))
    mysql.connection.commit()

###################### FLASK #########################
@app.route('/')
def index():
    storeDB('temp') #Here it works
    return 'Hello World'
```

If I access to `localhost` it shows the "Hello World" text in browser and updates the DB; otherwise, if I receive a MQTT message, it is shown on terminal but not updated the DB.
Thanks.

Comment: Well, I guess the problem comes from the `flask-mysqldb` package. I have tried it now using the native MySQLdb Python package (`MySQLdb`)  and it works perfectly (a little more "tricky" but working, just what I expected).

I know this is not a solution by itself because I'm using another package, but it's another way to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have it working using the `MySQLdb`package:

```py
import MySQLdb

try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect("HOST", "USER", "PASS", "DB")
except:
    print("Problem creating DB connection")
    sys.exit()

cursor = db.cursor()

def storeDB(param_text1, param_text2, param_text3):
    query = """INSERT INTO `DB`.`TABLE` (`fullname`, `phone`, `email`) VALUES ('""" + \
        param_text1+"""','"""+param_text2+"""','"""+param_text3+"""');"""

    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        db.commit()
        print('DB updated')
    except:
        db.rollback()
        print("Problem updating DB :(")
```